# Doctrine Migrations: versioning auto-generated classes

Tags: git, symfony, version-control, doctrine-orm, doctrine-migrations

I was wondering wether it is a good practice or not to add the auto-generated classes from doctrine migrations to your version control system ?

What would be the advantages/disadvantages of doing so ?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I would say so, yes. I am trying to figure out how to get D2 to generate migration classes so I can commit them to SVN each change I make. Why wouldn't you want the ability to roll your database back when you roll your code back as well? To me it makes a lot of sense.